# rails_admin dashboard/secondary_navigation customization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

Any chance to customize dashboard or secondary navigation?

Yes i can create `app/view/rails_admin/main/dashboard.html.haml` and redesign whole page from scratch.
But what should I do if I want just add simple partial before and safe current content?

In case with secondary navigation I tried to replace `_secondary_navigation.html.haml` in all places where partials could be - nothing happens.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
app/views/layouts/rails_admin/_secondary_navigation.html.haml
```

Here is the place were it should live.