# Rails Admin Customization: embed html view into dashboard

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-admin

We have removed the dashboard and the history from the rails admin starting page:

[image]

Now we want to embed a google analytics page for users to see the dashboards from GA.
This page consists of some simple HTML.

**QUESTION: How do you embed html pages in the Rails Admin Dashboard.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer was very simple, I needed to create the following file:

```
views/rails_admin/main/dashboard.html.erb
```

And this overwrites the standard dashboard, easy as that.

Found the information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8942025/rails-admin-dashboard-secondary-navigation-customization)

Answer (score 0):

I can provide a partial answer to your question which is a complete answer to your question. The answer to your question is to use a partial:

> Partial templates - usually just called "partials" - are another device for breaking the  rendering process into more manageable chunks. With a partial, you can move the code for rendering a particular piece of a response to its own file.

[Full details in the Layouts and Rendering documentation.](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials)